# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in python for math expression

Tags: python-2.7, syntax-error

i'm not used with python. just know the basic things.
i'm using math operation in python for calculation of inverse jacobian which has super long character in one lines.
my question is 'do the python has limit character in one line?'
or how to make a right module in python?
or which operation in math for python that not allowed?

my python program is designed for [ROS platform](http://www.ros.org/),
and this is part of my program:

```
class Skelplot():
    def __init__(self):
        ....
        self.q_raw      =[0,0,0]
        self.dq_ref     =[0,0,0]
        ....

        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            ...
            dx = x_now - right_hand.x()
            dy = y_now - right_hand.y()
            dz = z_now - right_hand.z()

            self.inverse_jacobian(dx,dy,dz)

            self.q_raw[0] = self.dq_ref[0] + self.q_raw[0]
            self.q_raw[1] = self.dq_ref[1] + self.q_raw[1]
            self.q_raw[2] = self.dq_ref[2] + self.q_raw[2]
            ...

    def inverse_jacobian(self, dx, dy, dz):
        self.dq_ref[0] = (-(5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[2]) + 5*sin(q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) + 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[2]) - 15*sin(self.q_raw[0]) + 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]))/(cos(self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1])/2 + cos(2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - cos(self.q_raw[1]) - cos(self.q_raw[2]) - 5/2))*dx + ((5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[2]) + 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) + 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[2]) - 15*cos(self.q_raw[0]) + 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]))/(cos(self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1])/2 + cos(2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - cos(self.q_raw[1]) - cos(self.q_raw[2]) - 5/2))*dy
        self.dq_ref[1] = (-(5*sin(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[1]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1]) + 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[2]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) - 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1]) + 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*sin(self.q_raw[0]) + 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]))/(cos(self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1])/2 + cos(2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - cos(self.q_raw[1]) - cos(self.q_raw[2]) - 5/2))*dx + ((5*cos(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[1]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1]) + 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[2]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) - 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1]) + 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*cos(self.q_raw[0]) + 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]))/(cos(self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1])/2 + cos(2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - cos(self.q_raw[1]) - cos(self.q_raw[2]) - 5/2))*dy   
        self.dq_ref[2] = (-(10*sin(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[2]) - 15*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[2]) + 5*sin(self.q_raw[0]) + 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]))/(cos(self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1])/2 + cos(2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - cos(self.q_raw[1]) - cos(self.q_raw[2]) - 5/2))*dx + ((10*cos(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[2]) - 15*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[2]) + 5*cos(self.q_raw[0]) + 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]))/(cos(self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1])/2 + cos(2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - cos(self.q_raw[1]) - cos(self.q_raw[2]) - 5/2))*dy
```

this is the respond:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adelleodel/ros/src/mekatron/nodes/skelplot.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Skelplot():
  File "/home/adelleodel/ros/src/mekatron/nodes/skelplot.py", line 203, in Skelplot
    self.dq_ref[2] = (-(10*sin(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[2]) - 15*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[2]) + 5*sin(self.q_raw[0]) + 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]))/(cos(self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1])/2 + cos(2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - cos(self.q_raw[1]) - cos(self.q_raw[2]) - 5/2))*dx + ((10*cos(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[2]) - 15*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[2]) + 5*cos(self.q_raw[0]) + 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]))/(cos(self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1])/2 + cos(2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - cos(self.q_raw[1]) - cos(self.q_raw[2]) - 5/2))*dy
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

i also tried with exception handling like this:

```
   ....
   def inverse_jacobian(self, dx, dy, dz):
      try:
          self.dq_ref[0] : ..
          self.dq_ref[1] : ..
          self.dq_ref[2] : ..
      except KeyError:
         pass
   ...
```

and the response is :

```
  File "/home/adelleodel/ros/src/mekatron/nodes/skelplot.py", line 204
    self.dq_ref[2] = (-(10*sin(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[2]) - 15*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[2]) + 5*sin(self.q_raw[0]) + 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 5*sin(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]))/(cos(self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1])/2 + cos(2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - cos(self.q_raw[1]) - cos(self.q_raw[2]) - 5/2))*dx + ((10*cos(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[2]) - 15*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + 10*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[1]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + self.q_raw[2]) + 5*cos(self.q_raw[0]) + 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] - self.q_raw[1] - self.q_raw[2]) - 5*cos(self.q_raw[0] + 2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]))/(cos(self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1])/2 + cos(2*self.q_raw[2]) + cos(2*self.q_raw[1] + 2*self.q_raw[2]) - cos(self.q_raw[1]) - cos(self.q_raw[2]) - 5/2))*dy
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so, could you which one did i go wrong?
thankyou.

Comment: `NameError` looks like indentation problem. Are you sure it's correct (not mixing up tabs and spaces, correct amount for each code block?) About second error, since it occurs on `self.dq_ref[2]`, problem is most likely somewhere in `..` in your second snippet.

Comment: thankyou for your fast-respons :). i'm sure the identation is correct. i just trying commented the last of that lines (self.dq_ref[2]...) with '#' and it work. but i need self.dq_ref[2] data for my program. so it's not solved yet for me.

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code into my Python2.7 and it doesn't give me any error. I suppose it is due to that you didn't use a constant indentation, make sure you use tab or the same of space all the time. You may consider choosing a proper IDE such as Spyder or Pycharm, they will do all this for you.

Comment: actually, i don't know it's python 2.7 or python 3.. after i list my installed package, i had python 3 in my system as well. i'm usually using Sublime for programming. and run it all in terminal. i'll consider your answer. thank you for your respons :)

Comment: @adelleodel, if you are using Windows, then I strongly recommend you to use [Winpython](https://winpython.github.io/) as a Python starter, it saves you a lot of trouble and have `Spyder` wrapped in by default and may more useful pacakges.